# borrar registro php

Tags: php, mysqli

No entiendo porque no se me ejecuta este codigo para borrar un usuario mediante la introduccion de un email:

```
<div class="lista-usuarios">
<h2>Lista de usuarios: </h2> <br>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <button type="submit" name="borrar_usuario">Eliminar</button>
</form>

<?php

foreach ($usuarios as $value) { 
  if ($value === 'adminmanager@gmail.com') {?>
     <li id=<?php echo $value; ?> class='usuario'> <?php echo $value ?> </li> <?php }else{ ?>
     <li id=<?php echo $value; ?> class='usuario'> <?php echo $value ?> 
     <a href="#" onclick='preguntar(<?php echo $value; ?>)'>Eliminar</a>
     </li>
<?php
}
}

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

if (isset($_POST['borrar_usuario'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $sql_borrar = 'DELETE FROM usuarios where email='. $_POST['email'] .'';
        $mysqli->query($sql_borrar);
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba esto: `$sql_borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where email = '".$_POST['email']."'";`

Comment: de sintaxis no creo que sea, lo he intentado de todas formas y nada, no se cual sera el error... @Stn

Comment: quita el `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` del `form`

Comment: la sintáxis que te recomendó @Stn es la correcta para este caso

Comment: @Stn que pongo en su defecto?

Comment: En la condición tu estas usando `isset` dos veces, pero solo lo tienes que usar una ves: `isset` determina si la variable esta definida y para determinar que un campo no este vació, debes usar `empty`. En vez de usar esto `if (isset($_POST['email']))`, hazlo asi: `if (!empty($_POST['email']))`. Prueba y dime.

Comment: Recuerda cambiar también esto: `$sql_borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where email = '".$_POST['email']."'";`

Answer (score 0):

Aqui puede haber un error de sintaxis. Las comillas.

```
 $sql_borrar = 'DELETE FROM usuarios where email='. $_POST['email'] .'';
```

Debería de ser así.

```
 $sql_borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where email='. $_POST['email'] .'";
```

o así .

```
 $sql_borrar = 'DELETE FROM usuarios where email=". $_POST["email"] ."';
```

Hay que tener cuidado con las comillas simples en php, espero te ayude.

Comment: nada, ni de una forma ni de la otra, se ejecuta pero no hace nada